# Android - Un código con cero errores, pero cuya Aplicación no se ejecuta

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, lenguaje-compilado, database-android

Cordial saludo.

A modo de aprendizaje vengo o estoy tratando de desarrollar una app poco a poco, es un proyecto de app tipo tablero kanban.  Inicialmente cuando corria bien, solo eran las clases para proyecto, se ejecutaba presentando los 3 proyectos de ejemplo en la pantalla y a cada uno le asignaba un color (view cards); pero ahora que agregue los procesos para el usuario solo presenta un msg de error que indica lo siguiente:
"System UI ins't respondíng.  Close App/Wait" (Imagen anexa), y no muestra nada de la aplicación, solo el mensaje en pantalla esperando que tome una decisión de si cierro la aplicación o espero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación pego el código de mis clases y el AndroidManifest, no comprendo que ocurre o que error no permite abrir la interfaz de la aplicación.

```
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Knbktlnbrd"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Knbktlnbrd">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

/******************************************************************************************/

DatabaseHelper.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class DatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        val createTableQuery = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${User.TABLE_NAME} (
                    ${User.COLUMN_CELULAR} REAL,
                    ${User.COLUMN_NOMBRE} TEXT,
                    ${User.COLUMN_CARGO} INTEGER,
                    ${User.COLUMN_ROL} INTEGER
                )
            """.trimIndent()
        db.execSQL(createTableQuery)

        val createProyectoTableQuery = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${Proyecto.TABLE_NAME} (
            ${Proyecto.COLUMN_ID_PROYECTO} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            ${Proyecto.COLUMN_NOMBRE} TEXT,
            ...
        )
    """.trimIndent()
        db.execSQL(createProyectoTableQuery)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // Aquí puedes implementar la lógica para actualizar la base de datos si hay cambios en la estructura
        // Por ejemplo, puedes eliminar la tabla existente y crear una nueva versión de la tabla
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${User.TABLE_NAME}")
        //onCreate(db)
    }

    fun insertUser(user: User): Long {
        val database = writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(User.COLUMN_CELULAR, user.celular)
            put(User.COLUMN_NOMBRE, user.nombre)
            put(User.COLUMN_CARGO, user.cargo)
            put(User.COLUMN_ROL, user.rol)
        }
        return database.insert(User.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues)
    }

    fun updateUser(user: User): Int {
        val database = writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(User.COLUMN_NOMBRE, user.nombre)
            put(User.COLUMN_CARGO, user.cargo)
            put(User.COLUMN_ROL, user.rol)
        }
        return database.update(
            User.TABLE_NAME,
            contentValues,
            "${User.COLUMN_CELULAR} = ?",
            arrayOf(user.celular.toString())
        )
    }

    fun deleteUser(user: User): Int {
        val database = writableDatabase
        return database.delete(
            User.TABLE_NAME,
            "${User.COLUMN_CELULAR} = ?",
            arrayOf(user.celular.toString())
        )
    }

    fun getAllUsers(): List<User> {
        val userList = mutableListOf<User>()
        val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM ${User.TABLE_NAME}"
        val database = readableDatabase
        val cursor: Cursor? = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
        cursor?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val celular = it.getDouble(it.getColumnIndex(User.COLUMN_CELULAR))
                    val nombre = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(User.COLUMN_NOMBRE))
                    val cargo = it.getInt(it.getColumnIndex(User.COLUMN_CARGO))
                    val rol = it.getInt(it.getColumnIndex(User.COLUMN_ROL))
                    val user = User(celular, nombre, cargo, rol)
                    userList.add(user)
                } while (it.moveToNext())
            }
        }
        return userList
    }

    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "knbktlnbrd.db"
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
    }
}

/******************************************************************************************/

MainActivity.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.knbktlnbrd.ui.theme.KnbktlnbrdTheme
import com.example.knbktlnbrd.DatabaseHelper


import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import com.example.knbktlnbrd.UserAdapter


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: ProjectAdapter
    private lateinit var dbHelper: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        /*setContent {
            KnbktlnbrdTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = ProjectAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        dbHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)

        loadProjects()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_add_project -> {
                // Abrir la actividad de creación de proyectos
                // Implementa la lógica según tus necesidades
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    private fun loadProjects() {
        val db: SQLiteDatabase = dbHelper.readableDatabase
        val projection = arrayOf("Id_Proyecto", "Nombre") // Columnas que deseas obtener
        val mainLayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.projectContainer)

        val cursor: Cursor = db.query(
            //"KnbProy",
            "proyecto",
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )

        val projects = mutableListOf<Project>()

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val projectId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id_Proyecto"))
            val projectName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Nombre"))

            // Genera un color pastel diferente para cada tarjeta
            val cardColor = generatePastelColor()

            val project = Project(projectId, projectName, cardColor)
            projects.add(project)
        }

        cursor.close()
        db.close()

        adapter.setProjects(projects)

        // Aplicar estilo de esquinas redondeadas y separación entre las viewcards
        //val cardRadius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.view_card_radius)
        val cardRadiusValue = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.view_card_radius)

        val cardRadius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.view_card_radius)
        val cardMargin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.view_card_margin)

        for (project in projects) {
            val viewCard = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.view_card, null) as CardView

            val cardLayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            cardLayoutParams.setMargins(cardMargin, cardMargin, cardMargin, cardMargin)
            viewCard.layoutParams = cardLayoutParams
            viewCard.radius = cardRadius

            // Resto del código para configurar los elementos de la viewcard

            mainLayout.addView(viewCard)
        }
    }

    private fun generatePastelColor(): Int {
        val random = java.util.Random()
        val hue = random.nextInt(360).toFloat()
        val pastelColor = Color.HSVToColor(floatArrayOf(hue, 0.3f, 1f))
        return pastelColor
    }

}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    KnbktlnbrdTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

/******************************************************************************************/

ProjectAdapter.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ProjectAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectAdapter.ProjectViewHolder>() {
    private var projects: List<Project> = emptyList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProjectViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_project, parent, false)
        return ProjectViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProjectViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val project = projects[position]
        holder.bind(project)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return projects.size
    }

    fun setProjects(projects: List<Project>) {
        this.projects = projects
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ProjectViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val projectNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.projectNameTextView)

        fun bind(project: Project) {
            projectNameTextView.text = project.projectName
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(project.cardColor)
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                // Abrir la actividad de creación de proyectos con la información del proyecto seleccionado
                // Implementa la lógica según tus necesidades
            }
        }
    }
}

/******************************************************************************************/

Project.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

data class Project(
    val projectId: Int,
    val projectName: String,
    val cardColor: Int
)

/******************************************************************************************/

Proyecto.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

class Proyecto {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "Proyecto"
        const val COLUMN_ID_PROYECTO = "Id_Proyecto"
        const val COLUMN_NOMBRE = "Nombre"
        // Agrega aquí las demás columnas de la tabla "Proyecto"
    }
}

/******************************************************************************************/

User.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase

class User(val celular: Double, val nombre: String, val cargo: Int, val rol: Int) {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "Usuario"
        const val COLUMN_CELULAR = "Celular"
        const val COLUMN_NOMBRE = "Nombre"
        const val COLUMN_CARGO = "Cargo"
        const val COLUMN_ROL = "Rol"

        fun createUserTable(database: SQLiteDatabase) {
            val createTableQuery = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME (
                    $COLUMN_CELULAR REAL,
                    $COLUMN_NOMBRE TEXT,
                    $COLUMN_CARGO INTEGER,
                    $COLUMN_ROL INTEGER
                )
            """.trimIndent()
            database.execSQL(createTableQuery)
        }
    }

    fun insertUser(database: SQLiteDatabase): Long {
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CELULAR, celular)
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NOMBRE, nombre)
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CARGO, cargo)
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ROL, rol)
        return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues)
    }

    fun updateUser(database: SQLiteDatabase): Int {
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NOMBRE, nombre)
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CARGO, cargo)
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ROL, rol)
        return database.update(
            TABLE_NAME,
            contentValues,
            "$COLUMN_CELULAR = ?",
            arrayOf(celular.toString())
        )
    }

    fun deleteUser(database: SQLiteDatabase): Int {
        return database.delete(
            TABLE_NAME,
            "$COLUMN_CELULAR = ?",
            arrayOf(celular.toString())
        )
    }

    fun getUser(database: SQLiteDatabase): Cursor {
        return database.query(
            TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            "$COLUMN_CELULAR = ?",
            arrayOf(celular.toString()),
            null,
            null,
            null
        )
    }
}

/******************************************************************************************/

UserAdapter.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.knbktlnbrd.R
import com.example.knbktlnbrd.User


class UserAdapter(private val context: Context, private var userList: List<User>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false)
        return UserViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user = userList[position]
        holder.bind(user)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    fun setUsers(users: List<User>) {
        userList = users
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class UserViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val celularTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCelular)
        private val nombreTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNombre)
        private val cargoTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCargo)
        private val rolTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRol)

        fun bind(user: User) {
            celularTextView.text = user.celular.toString()
            nombreTextView.text = user.nombre
            cargoTextView.text = user.cargo.toString()
            rolTextView.text = user.rol.toString()
        }
    }
}


/******************************************************************************************/

UsuariosCrearActivity.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class UsuariosCrearActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var celularEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var nombreEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var cargoEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var rolEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var guardarButton: Button

    private lateinit var dbHelper: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuarios_crear)

        celularEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCelular)
        nombreEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre)
        cargoEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCargo)
        rolEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextRol)
        guardarButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonGuardar)

        dbHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)

        guardarButton.setOnClickListener { guardarUsuario() }
    }

    private fun guardarUsuario() {
        val celular = celularEditText.text.toString().toDouble()
        val nombre = nombreEditText.text.toString()
        val cargo = cargoEditText.text.toString().toInt()
        val rol = rolEditText.text.toString().toInt()

        val db: SQLiteDatabase = dbHelper.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put("celular", celular)
            put("nombre", nombre)
            put("cargo", cargo)
            put("rol", rol)
        }

        val newRowId = db.insert("usuario", null, values)

        db.close()

        if (newRowId != -1L) {
            // El usuario se guardó correctamente
            // Realizar cualquier acción adicional aquí, como mostrar un mensaje de éxito.
            finish()
        } else {
            // Ocurrió un error al guardar el usuario
            // Realizar cualquier acción adicional aquí, como mostrar un mensaje de error.
        }
    }
}


/******************************************************************************************/

UsuariosListarActivity.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class UsuariosListarActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var listaUsuarios: ListView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuarios_listar)

        listaUsuarios = findViewById(R.id.listaUsuarios)

        // Obtener la lista de usuarios desde la base de datos (puedes adaptar esto según tu implementación)
        val usuarios = obtenerUsuarios()

        // Crear un adaptador para mostrar los usuarios en la lista
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usuarios)

        // Asignar el adaptador a la lista
        listaUsuarios.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun obtenerUsuarios(): List<String> {
        // Aquí debes implementar la lógica para obtener la lista de usuarios desde la base de datos
        // y devolverla como una lista de cadenas (puedes adaptar esto según tu implementación)
        return listOf("Usuario 1", "Usuario 2", "Usuario 3")
    }
}


/******************************************************************************************/

UsuariosViewActivity.kt
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class UsuariosViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter
    private lateinit var dbHelper: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuarios_view)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuarios_listar)
        //recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listaUsuarios)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)
        val userList = databaseHelper.getAllUsers()
        adapter = UserAdapter(this, userList)

        //adapter = UserAdapter()
        adapter = UserAdapter(this, userList)


        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        dbHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)

        loadUsers()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_add_project -> {
                openUsuariosCrearActivity()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    private fun loadUsers() {
        val db: SQLiteDatabase = dbHelper.readableDatabase
        val projection = arrayOf("celular", "nombre", "cargo", "rol")

        val cursor: Cursor = db.query(
            "usuario",
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )

        val users = mutableListOf<User>()

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val celular = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("celular"))
            val nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nombre"))
            val cargo = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cargo"))
            val rol = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rol"))

            val user = User(celular, nombre, cargo, rol)
            users.add(user)
        }

        cursor.close()
        db.close()

        adapter.setUsers(users)
    }

    private fun openUsuariosCrearActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, UsuariosCrearActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}


/******************************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Hola. Revisa el Logcat, allí debería estar indicando por qué falla la aplicación.

Comment: "Cero errores", que no veas líneas rojas en tu código no significa que no haya errores. K iniciar tu aplicación, revisa tu logcat. Ahí es donde verás tus errores

Comment: A. Cedano, este es el Logcat arrojado al ejecutar la app en el emulador